# probability of sequence of exactly 3 heads

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A fair coin is tossed 5 times. What is the probability of getting a sequence of exactly 3 heads?

Attempt:

Sample space = $2^5 = 32$
\number of possible positions of first head = $5 - 3 + 1 = 3$
\number of ways the other 2 outcomes could occur = $2^2 = 4$

Therefore prob of exactly 3 heads in sequence = $\frac {3 × 4}{32} $

Should i count the ways that the other two outcomes could occur?

Comment: You have identified that there three locations where the string of three heads could begin.  Spend a little time thinking about what happens in the other two locations. Is there only one possibility, or are there multiple possibilities for the two remaining spots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us use your idea. If the sequence of consecutive heads begins at Position 1, then the next term must be T, and the last term can be chosen freely, $2$ choices.

If the sequence begins at  Position 2, everything is forced, we only have THHHT, $1$ choice.

And if the consecutive heads start at Position 3, our sequence must be of shape XTHHH, $2$ possibilities.

Comment: That makes sense, i was interpreting things along the lines that i could still obtain more than the 3 heads, but we only cared about exactly the 3 heads, but even then taking into consideration i would have to still add up all the different possibilities that could occur.....oddly i still would have gotten 12.

Comment: @dc3rd: Counting can be tricky. And it gets much harder for strings of length $\gt 6$, since we can have more than one string of H's of length exactly $3$.

Comment: I had to sit back and conceive an example and boy oh boy you're not lying. I guess i have a lot of practice on my hands. Suggestion of a good introductory undergrad combinatoric text?

Comment: About texts, unfortunately I do not know.